# run Chrome Remote Desktop without unlocking the target machine

Tags: remote-access, chrome-remote-desktop

So I'm trying to use Chrome Remote Desktop to access my work computer, and everything is working fine, but the issue is that logging in also unlocks the target machine.

This is a problem for me because when I'm working at home I'm less likely to lock my computer, meaning that I'm leaving my workstation unlocked.

Is there anyway to run chrome remote desktop such that when you enter credentials on host machine, the target isn't unlocked?

I've looked for this online, but I'm not able to get the right phrasing to let google do its magic for me.

My home machine is windows 10, my target machine is Windows 8.

Thank you for any information or help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are planning to use the same session of the target machine, there's no way to use it without unlocking the session.

To workaround on this for security purposes on host machine, you may:
1. Switch off the monitor in host machine (semi-secure)
2. Enable the chrome remote curtain mode, which means whenever the host is remotely connected, it always shows blank in host's monitor, and you should lock the host machine after you are done.